# UnityOfWork instance is created twice despite using Unity.MVC3 and HierarchicalLifetimeManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

I'm using Unity.MVC3 in my project.

I've implemented generic unit of work - `UnitOfWork<TContext>` and I want it to be created per request. So taking advantage of Unity.MVC3 I did it in this way:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>), typeof(UnitOfWork<>), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

I'm using mentioned UOW inside base repository. Base repository is used by some specific repositories and those specific repositories are used by some services.

Let's say we have UserRepository and UserService.

UserRepository constructor looks more or less like this:

```
    public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork<UserContext> unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {           
    }
```

Inside UserService I'm using UserRepository and I would like to have the same UOW instance as UserRepository uses:

```
public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository, IUnitOfWork<UserContext> unitOfWork)
{
}
```

While I'm using Unity.MVC3 and registered UOW using the HierarchicalLifetimeManager I should get the same UOW instance in both UserRepository and UserService, right?

The thing is that if I run website for the first time, two different UOW instances are created and for only one of this two instances Dispose method is invoked. When the page is loaded and I press refresh button everything seems to be correct - only one instance is created.

It seems like the problem appears for registered generic types.

If you would like to reproduce the problem you can download the [Unity.MVC3.Example](http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/580f45a682a5) code, make IExampleContext generic and try to run it.

Do you have any idea what can cause the problem and how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think that PerResolveLifetimeManager is what you need.

Creates just one UOW in the dependecy chain but every time you resolve a chain a new UOW is created.

HierarchicalLifetimeManager is the opposite behavior.

Comment: Hi. That would be perfect if I had one service per controller. But in my case I can have multiple services defined in controller. In that situation PerResolveLifetimeManager will not provide the same IUnitOfWork<UserContext> instance while resolving each services. I really need one instance per request.

Comment: Maybe you need to resolve an application layer class with multiple services. This allows you to have the services in the same dependecy chain. The application layer is the layer that coordinates services (if many is needed for an operation), use repositories to retrive data to pass it to services, manage uow for commit or rollback and handles errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my alternate solution:

I created PerRequestLifetimeManager:

```
public class PerRequestLifetimeManager<T> : LifetimeManager, IDisposable
{
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName];
    }
    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName);
    }
    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName] = newValue;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Inside UserDomain I registered IUnitOfWork type:

```
RegisterType<IUnitOfWork<UsersContext>, UnitOfWork<UsersContext>>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager<IUnitOfWork<UsersContext>>());
```

I created PerRequestLifetimeHttpModule and registered it in Web.config:

```
public class PerRequestLifetimeHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += (sender, e) => UnityDependencyResolver.DisposePerRequestLifetimeItems();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <add name="PerRequestLifetimeHttpModule" type="<namespace>.PerRequestLifetimeHttpModule, <assemblyName>" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer
```

And finally the last step - inside my custom UnityDependencyResolver I created DisposePerRequestLifetimeItems static function which is used in PerRequestLifetimeHttpModule:

```
public static void DisposePerRequestLifetimeItems()
{
    foreach (var item in HttpContext.Current.Items.OfType<DictionaryEntry>().Where(item => item.Value is IDisposable))
    {
        ((IDisposable)item.Value).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something I don't understand. In the Unity.MVC3 example the controllers are created through Unity, injecting services to the controllers. That means the two services (and repositories injected to services, and UOW injected to repositories) are in the same dependency chain. PerResolveLifetimeManager should cover your issue without any trick.